# Struts2 execAndWait and EJB user principal

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts2, ejb

I'm trying to add wait pages to slow response actions in my application.

In my EJB layer, I will sometimes call `SessionContext.getCallerPrincipal().getName()` if I need to refine the behavior based on the user.

This is now returning `UNAUTHENTICATED`.

I have tried creating the `InitialContext` and looking up the EJB from the prepare() method of the Action. The `execAndWait` interceptor is declared last. This also returns `UNAUTHENTICATED`.

For testing purposes I called the EJB function from the prepare method and that executes as the correct user.

I understand that `execAndWait` executes the action in a separate thread, but I didn't expect that it would execute as a different user. Is there a way around the behavior I'm seeing?

Comment: WebSphere 8.5, EJB 3.1, Java EE 6

Comment: I confirmed by applying an EJB role that the caller from the execAndWait Action is indeed a different user. Struts 2.3.16.3. I'm going to try 2.3.24.1 and see if it's fixed there.

Comment: Issue also exists in Struts 2.3.24.1

Comment: Best I can tell with research is that this is not possible with WebSphere without a change to Struts' implementation of org.apache.struts2.interceptor.BackgroundProcess. Processes spawned using java.util.Thread.start() are not managed and do not have JEE Context information. The technique is discouraged. There are platform specific mechanisms for creating new threads in a managed Context that could be used but are probably outside Struts' purview to use.